# Is there a way to create an UdpSocket without bind() for just send_to()?

Tags: rust

I'm trying to do the equivalent of [this piece of Ruby](https://github.com/davydovanton/AnyBar_rb/blob/0431c2bb3906bab4bb561b211a90b470098e1523/lib/any_bar.rb#L14-L20):

```
def color=(color)
  @color = color
  any_bar = UDPSocket.new
  any_bar.connect HOSTNAME, @port
  any_bar.send @color, 0
  any_bar.close
end
```

I can't see any other way to [initialize a `UdpSocket` from the Rust API documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/net/struct.UdpSocket.html) without `bind()`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I would try `::bind("0.0.0.0:0")` - this should let the O/S choose an IP/port for you. This might be good enough for a transient socket to send a simple datagram with.

*Note: this is what happens too when using sendto() on an unbound UDP socket too, e.g. using the fd returned from the socket() system call without calling bind() - the O/S allocates an IP/port to send your datagram from.*

Comment: I'm doing that now. Is this the equivalent of the Ruby example? I'm curious if the Ruby and friends version just tosses a packet out on the network without binding or if it binds like this behind the scenes.

Comment: Oh, I just reflected on your comment on the question. I guess so. Thanks!

Comment: This doesn't appear to work if I want to support either ipv4 or ipv6 sends. When unbound

Comment: @CodySchafer I wonder what the logic is then in Ruby for that.

Comment: IPv4 vs IPv6 is done by creating a Socket of right `AF_INET` or `AF_INET6` address families. You'd have to also `::bind()` different for IPv6 - `::/0` if I'm not mistaken